# Firefox: Possible values for browser.newtab.url?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 16 configuration is the following value:

```
browser.newtab.url: about:newtab
```

What are other possible values here? In [Mozilla knowledge base](http://mzl.la/LFouVP) only the values `about:newtab` and `about:blank` are mentioned. Is there something to load the currently set homepage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put any URL there, e.g. `http://superuser.com`

There is no link to the homepage in the about:-scheme, but you can enter your homepage manually, of course.

One thing you might be interested in putting there is `about:home`, that will give you the default homepage of Firefox. You'll find a list of all about:-pages [here](http://uglydawg.hubpages.com/hub/Beyond-Firefoxs-aboutconfig).

Comment: But this will not use the currently set homepage. Is there something generic?

Comment: It is no longer possible to do this. One solution is middle-clicking the home-button instead of opening a new tab. Or you can just install a [browser extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/).